# Application for upload a file via HTTP

Tags: windows-7, windows, http, upload

I need upload a set of files via http. do you know any application to accomplish this?

**UPDATE**

I have access and permissions to read and write, only via http to this location (Linux Server)

OS is Windows 7.

Comment: What do you mean HTTP? You want a web based file uploader? Where are you putting the files? This needs to be made clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're not referring to plain form-based file uploads via your web browser, then I'm going to assume you're actually referring to HTTP uploads via **WebDAV**, Web-based Distributed Authoring and Versioning. See [WebDAV - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV).  It is supported by many web servers.

Windows already includes the capability to upload to WebDAV-enabled HTTP locations. You don't need special software.  Windows refers to WebDAV shares as "web folders" and you can access them with Windows Explorer.

Additional information:

- [Web Folders setup for Windows 7](http://faq.mydocsonline.com/201/web-folders-setup-for-windows-7/)
- [How-to use WebDAV on Windows Vista and Windows 7](http://it.knightnet.org.uk/2009/05/how-to-use-webdav-on-windows-vista-and.html)

Answer (score 0):

A web browser should suffice for regular form-based HTTP uploads, we'd need more details on the situation to give you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using cURL with HTTP POST http://curl.haxx.se/

See example on:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84619/how-do-i-make-a-post-request-with-curl

Comment: `curl` is a part of recent versions of Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16216825/1833960